# How to respond to a Stripe webhook if I receive a Connect account update before I create the Connect account entity in my db?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm using [Stripe](https://www.stripe.com) to add Connect accounts (bank accounts) for my users and have set up my server to listen to incoming webhooks. In my controller, I create a Stripe Connect account and then fill in my own StripeAccount entity with the newly created account data, like this:

```
// Stripe API call to create bank account
var service = new AccountService();
account = await service.CreateAsync(options);

// create a new entity in my db 
var stripeAccount = new StripeAccount {
    UserId = userFromRepo.Id,
    stripeAccount.AccountId = account.Id;
    // fill in other fields...
};

_unitOfWork.Repository<StripeAccount>().Add(stripeAccount);
var success = await _unitOfWork.Complete();
if (success) {
    // send out email to user
}
```

Stripe immediately sends me a webhook **AccountUpdated** before my server has time to save the new entity to my db. Usually their timestamp is the same for **AccountCreated** and **AccountUpdated** events.

**Question** - So in my controller listening for webhooks, should I check for my entity to see if it's been created and if it doesn't exist send a status not found 404 response back to Stripe? And then wait for Stripe to send it again?

**FYI** - According to their documentation page regarding [built in retries](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#built-in-retries), they say just return a status 200, and they say - "If Stripe doesn’t quickly receive a 2xx response status code for an event, we mark the event as failed and stop trying to send it to your endpoint."

If anyone has any advice to give me regarding this I would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of thumb that *Stripe only cares whether you respond 200 to their webhook request*. Doesn't matter if you return 404 or 500 to a webhook event, they will mark it as incomplete.

You seem to have a race condition between logic in listening to Stripe webhook and saving entity to your db. You can simply wait for the saving logic finished to start calling Stripe API (and trigger webhook event) or you will need a locking or queuing mechanism for handling them asynchronously.

Comment: If Stripe marks it as incomplete will they resend it? To your second point, I really can't wait for the saving condition to finish before I send the call to Stripe, triggering the webhook, because all the data I need to save is coming from Stripe. Stripe is used by 1K+ companies, haven't others been frustrated with this as well?

Comment: Yes they will retry the failed event. I guess you would want to reconsider which information you need when processing webhook event (considering the id might still be saving into your db and isn't available yet). If you can delay that logic into a later timing then there won't be a race condition.

Comment: I think at this point I'm going to test out logic where, after receiving the webhook for a account creation, if I haven't finished creating my entity yet I'll send Stripe a not found status (404) then I'll wait until Stripe sends it again. It says on their site they retry a couple of times in the first 3 hours and then taper off after that. My entity should be created within seconds, so any retry should be ok!

Comment: The only other option I can think of would be to create my entity (it would be empty of data) and take the ID generated from it and pass that to the "MetaData" field with Stripe. Then I could look at the metadata (ID) in the webhook and populate by that data, but this method might get a little messy as I'm not sure all metadata created at the beginning will get propagated through with each webhook sent out.